# Silverlight Behavior: DataContext of AssociatedObject changes

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datacontext, dependency-properties, behavior

I've written an Interactivity Behavior (from Blend SDK) , which can be attached to a DataGrid, and does some magic with the DataGrid's columns based on the ViewModel in the DataContext of the DataGrid.
Since the DataContext can be set later, I have to listen for DataContext changes in the behavior. So, I've bound a DependencyProperty to the Associated DataGrid's DataContext, like this:

```
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, SourceProperty, new Binding("DataContext") { Source = AssociatedObject });
```

This line is hit, so the binding does happen.

Now the tricky part:
if I call

```
datagrid.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

everything works perfectly. But, if the datagrid is contained in some UserControl (not necessarily its immediate child) and I want to call

```
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

the callback of the Source property DOESN'T fire. I debugged it, the datagrid.DataContext is set, so the DataContext is inherited through the visual tree, as it should be, if I manually call update on the behavior, it does see the DataContext, but nothing happens automatically.
I don't want to name the DataGrid instance, I don't want to name the behavior, since there can be any number of those in one UserControl, I want to set the UserControl's DataContext and let the DependencyProperty system work its magic.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to set binding in an opposite way: SetBinding(AssociatedObject, FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, new Binding("Source") { Source = this, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay});

Comment: @vorrtex: That sounds like an answer not a comment.  Perhaps its placed strategically because its wrong.

Comment: @vorrtex: everything is the same, nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something simpler:-

```
  BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, SourceProperty, new Binding());
```

This should give you the DataContext object.  A binding without a `Path` returns the source object.  A binding without an explicit `Source` returns the current `DataContext`.

The question is does does the `DataContext` of `this` (the behaviour) aquire its value from the `DataGrid` to which its attached?  I think it probably does.

Comment: Wow, that's a surprise. Behavior is only a DependencyObject, and DataContext is on FrameworkElement, but miraculously it works.